# A matrix with integers entries and complex solution.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $3\times 4$ and $b$ be $3\times 1$ matrix with integers entries. Suppose that the system $AX=b$ has a complex solution. Prove that the system $AX=b$  has a rational solution and set of all real solution of $AX=0$ has a basis consisting of rationals solutions ?.

Comment: it is clear that it has infinite solution corresponding to b but how it has rational solution?

Comment: Any solution can be found by row reduction, and row reduction preserves rationality of all the entries.

Comment: ok are you saying that we can reduce the matrix inti Echelon form by only row operation using scalars upto rationals only?

Comment: Of course. You use elementary row operations, and if you start with integers, you never have to use non-rationals at any step.

Comment: You read the basis off the reduced row-echelon form, so everything in sight is rational.

Comment: Do you know how to find a basis for the set of real solutions of $Ax=0$?

Comment: ok just reduce in echelon form and give rational values to free variables....am i correct??

Comment: That should work.

Comment: ok thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1):

If you have Complex solution to $Ax=b$ (imaginary part of complex solution is not zero) then it is sure that you have at least one non-zero solution to $Ax=0$.To illustrate this:

Let $A$ be a $3×4$ and $b$ be a $3×1$ matrix with integer entries.Suppose that the system $Ax=b$ has a complex solution. Let this complex solution is $u$= 
$
  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
x_1+i\times y_1  \\
x_2+i\times y_2 \\
x_3+i\times y_3\end{array} \right) $

=
$
  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
x_1  \\
x_2 \\
x_3\end{array} \right) $ + 
$i
  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
y_1  \\
y_2 \\
y_3\end{array} \right) $= $X+i \times Y$ ( where $Y$ is not a zero vector)

So this system of linear equation can be written as: $A(X+i \times Y)=b +0$ since entries of $b$ are integers..i.e., real so we can consider it as two system of linear equations: $A X=b$ and $AY=0$   that means $AX=0$ has a solution other than zero. (which is $Y$). So it is clear that null space has dimension greater than equals to 1.